# Android 2.3.3 and XmlPullParser.nextText()

Tags: android, xmlpullparser, android-pullparser

Article on this [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/12/watch-out-for-xmlpullparsernexttext.html) (android developer's blog) says:

> Using XmlPullParser is an efficient and maintainable way to parse XML
>   on Android. Historically Android has had two implementations of this
>   interface:
>
> ```
> - KXmlParser, via XmlPullParserFactory.newPullParser().
> - ExpatPullParser, via Xml.newPullParser().
> ```
>
> The implementation from Xml.newPullParser() had a bug where calls to
>   nextText() didn’t always advance to the END_TAG as the documentation
>   promised it would. As a consequence, some apps may be working around
>   the bug with extra calls to next() or nextTag():
>   ...

I do not understand if this refers to `XmlPullParserFactory.newPullParser()` or `Xml.newPullParser()` or to both.

For example, will this code on Android 2.3.3 and lower create a bug:

```
XmlPullParser xpp = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser();
int event = xpp.getEventType();
while (...event not end doc and tag not equal search term...){
     event = xpp.next();
}
myClass.setSomeText(xpp.nextText());
```

Comment: It only says `Xml.newPullParser() had a bug[...]` so, `XmlPullParserFactory.newPullParser()` should be fine..

Comment: @Jave Yes, but `nextText` is available to your object create via each way (factory and non-factory).

Comment: Yes, they are both subclasses of the `XmlPullParser` interface, so they have a lot of method in common, although the implementation of these methods are different, so one of them (`ExpatPullParser`) had a bug that the other didn't have.